# metodo encadeado em classe com métodos estáticos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Boa tarde a todos!!!
Como faço para criar um método encadeado, sendo ele, um método estático? 
exemplo:

> echo classe::meumétodo->$variável;

Obrigado

Comment: defina ele como  static ao invez de colocar public/private na variavel declara ela na classe como  static e chama classe::meumetodo::$variavel

Answer (score 0):

Copia isso e cola e veja como funciona, vá fazendo os testes.

```
class Test
{
    public static $attr = "Hello";
    public static function testa(){
        echo "Olá eu sou o testa";
        return new static();
    }
}
$ola = Test::testa()::$attr;
var_dump($ola);
```

O `new static()` retorna a classe `Test`